# SQL-Server - Попытка открыть доступ к бд, попытка экспорта бд

Tags: sql-server

Экспорт бд выдает ошибку, что не удалось подключиться к серверу.
Сервер пингуется. Удаленно подключиться к серверу не могу, выдает ошибку входа.

Сервер не в домене, влияет ли это на работу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в SSMS локально подключитесь, кликните в сервер - свойства - подключения - разрешить удаленные подключения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверьте включен ли протокол TCP/IP в Configuration Manager.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- включите разрешение на подключение через SQL авторизацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- создайте нового пользователя для подключения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Выберете роль public, укажите сопоставление с вашей БД, укажите схему по умолчанию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Добавьте разрешения на подключение и просмотр объектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для @WizarD51 "создайте нового пользователя для подключения и дайте ему права." -  предлагаю пояснить где необходимо создать пользователя и какие права ему необходимо выдать.

Comment: Поправил ответ в соответствии с замечаниями.

Comment: у  TCP/IP в свойствах еще нужно проверять чтобы была в строках "Активен" и "Включен" - да.