# При установлении соединения с SQL Server возникла ошибка

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

На новом компьютере установил Visual Studio и SQL Server пытаюсь запустить рабочий проект, который заботал на старом компе. Вываливаеться вот такая ошибка:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текст ошибки можно скопировать, а не вываливать скриншот!

Comment: @Dima   Добавил текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажать ПКМ на имя инстанса в SSMS.

В появившемся окне:
Выбрать блок **Connections**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установить галочку в указанном месте.

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: @Maksims https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726960/sql-server-Попытка-открыть-доступ-к-бд-попытка-экспорта-бд/726970#726970